# In pandas, how to display the most frequent diagnoses in dataframe, but only count 1 occurrence of the same diagnoses per patient

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas and python:

I have a large datasets with health records where patients have records of diagnoses.
How to display the most frequent diagnoses, but only count 1 occurrence of the same diagnoses per patient?


Example ('pid' is patient id. 'code' is the code of a diagnosis):

IN:

```
pid  code
1    A
1    B
1    A
1    A
2    A
2    A
2    B
2    A
3    B
3    C
3    D
4    A
4    A
4    A
4    B
```

OUT:

```
B    4
A    3
C    1
D    1
```

I would like to be able to use .isin .index if possible.

Example:
Remove all rows with less than 3 in frequency count in column 'code'

```
s = df['code'].value_counts().ge(3)
df = df[df['code'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby + nunique:

```
df.groupby(by='code').pid.nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[60]: 
code
B    4
A    3
D    1
C    1
Name: pid, dtype: int64
```

To remove all rows with less than 3 in frequency count in column 'code'

```
df.groupby(by='code').filter(lambda x: x.pid.nunique()>=3)
Out[55]: 
    pid code
0     1    A
1     1    B
2     1    A
3     1    A
4     2    A
5     2    A
6     2    B
7     2    A
8     3    B
11    4    A
12    4    A
13    4    A
14    4    B
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to sort them descending?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention `value_counts`

```
    df.groupby('code').pid.value_counts().count(level=0)
    Out[42]: 
    code
    A    3
    B    4
    C    1
    D    1
    Name: pid, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think half of the code in my thesis will be based on your answers, in the end ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `groupby` and `nunique()` functions to obtain a distinct count of patients that had each diagnosis. This should give you the result you need:

```
df[['pid', 'code']].groupby(['code']).nunique()
```